# ParseObjects from Android App not created on Parse Server

Tags: java, android, heroku, parse-server

I have deployed Parse Server on Heroku. The Mongo Lab and setup and everything is working fine. The server is successfully deployed on the parse server but I am not able to connect my android app to the parse server deployed on heroku.

I have configured the below details in my parse server index.js

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  serverURL: "https://parseservertest12.herokuapp.com",
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://heroku_jhwmv6c9:khhmh38a4u95krh1gbajni59rs@ds021034.mlab.com:21034/heroku_jhwmv6c9',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'myMasterKey' //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
});
```

[Check my Heroku Creditentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Bapd.png)

Here is my Application.java Class

```
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .applicationId("myAppId")
            .clientKey("myMasterKey")
            .server("https://parseservertest12.herokuapp.com/parse")
    .build()
    );

      ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
      gameScore.put("score", 1337);
      gameScore.put("playerName", "Sean Plott");
      gameScore.put("cheatMode", false);
      gameScore.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
          public void done(ParseException e) {
              if (e == null) {
                  Log.i("Parse", "Save Succeeded");
              } else {
                  Log.i("Parse", "Save Failed");
              }
          }
      });


      ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    // Optionally enable public read access.
    // defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
  }
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <application
        android:name=".StarterApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/parse_app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
            android:value="@string/parse_client_key" />
```

This is the Strings.xml

```
<string name="parse_app_id">myAppId</string>
    <string name="parse_client_key">myMasterKey</string>
```

I have tried resolving this issue a lot of times and referred to many online solutions but my method and everything seems correct but I am still not able to connect the android application to my parse server. My application is ready on the Android device but connecting to the parse server has caused me alot of delay please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Running parse server with the VERBOSE=1 environment variable will help you debug this issue.

Also, can you try replacing your serverURL with https://parseservertest12.herokuapp.com/parse/ (adding a trailing `/`). In the android app.